# Checking the antipode for a dg-Hopf algebra on algebra generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

If $H$ is a bialgebra and $S \colon H \to H$ is an algebra antihomomorphism such that the identities
\begin{equation}
  m \circ (S \otimes {\operatorname{id}}) \circ \Delta(x)
  =
  \varepsilon(x) 1_H
  \quad
  \text{and}
  \quad
  m \circ ({\operatorname{id}} \otimes S) \circ \Delta(x)
  =
  \varepsilon(x) 1_H
  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
hold on an algebra generating set of $H$ then it follows that $S$ is already an antipode for $H$, making it a Hopf algebra.

> How does this criterion generalize to differential graded Hopf algebras?

(I want to use this generalization to show that for a dg-vector space $V$ the induced dg-bialgebra structure on $\operatorname{T}(V)$, for which $V$ consists of primitive elements, is a dg-Hopf algebra.)

---

My attempt:
It tried to show that for a dg-bialgebra $H$ and a homomorphism of dg-algebras $S \colon H \to H^{\mathrm{op}}$ the identities $(1)$ only need to be checked on an algebra generating set of $H$.
For this I tried to check that the sets
\begin{align*}
  H'
  &=
  \{
    x \in H
  \mid
    \Delta \circ (S \otimes {\operatorname{id}}) \circ m(x) = \varepsilon(x) 1_H
  \} \,,
  \\
  H''
  &=
  \{
    x \in H
  \mid
    \Delta \circ ({\operatorname{id}} \otimes S) \circ m(x) = \varepsilon(x) 1_H
  \}
\end{align*}
are subalgebras of $H$ (since this is what is done in the non-dg case).
But this doesn’t seem to work:
We have for all $x, y \in H$ that
\begin{align*}
  m \circ (S \otimes {\operatorname{id}}) \circ \Delta(xy)
  &=
  \sum_{(xy)} S( (xy)_{(1)} ) (xy)_{(2)}
  \\
  &=
  \sum_{(x),(y)} (-1)^{|x_{(2)}| |y_{(1)}|}
  S( x_{(1)} y_{(1)} ) x_{(2)} y_{(2)}
  \\
  &=
  \sum_{(x), (y)} (-1)^{|x_{(2)}| |y_{(1)}| + |x_{(1)}| |y_{(1)}|}
  S( y_{(1)} ) S( x_{(1)} ) x_{(2)} y_{(2)}
  \\
  &=
  \sum_{(x), (y)} (-1)^{|x| |y_{(1)}|}
  S( y_{(1)} ) S( x_{(1)} ) x_{(2)} y_{(2)} \,.
\end{align*}
The first occuring sign comes from the identity $\Delta(xy) = \sum_{(x),(y)} (-1)^{|x_{(2)}| |y_{(1)}|} x_{(1)} y_{(1)} \otimes x_{(2)} y_{(2)}$ (which comes from $\Delta \colon H \to H \otimes H$ being a homomorphism of dg-algebras), and the second sign comes from $S$ being a homomorphism of dg-algebras into $H^{\mathrm{op}}$ (whose multiplication $*$ is given by $x*y = (-1)^{|x| |y|} y x$).
I had hoped that the appearing signs cancel out, so that one can use for $x, y \in H'$ the equalities $\sum_{(x)} S(x_{(1)}) x_{(2)} = \varepsilon(x) 1_H$ and $\sum_{(y)} S(y_{(1)}) y_{(2)} = \varepsilon(y) 1_H$.
But this does not seem to work.

Comment: For future reference (I was actually looking for a proof of the result myself here on MSE): the result for Hopf algebras you state at the beginning without proof is proven in Dascalescu, Nastasescu, Raianu, _Hopf Algebras: An Introduction_, Lemma 4.3.3